# Compute column insert

Tags: sql-server

I have added a compute column, but I get an error when I insert the values, I left out the column name where the compute column is. I read somewhere that you don't include it in your insert.

> Msg 110, Level 15, State 1, Line 641 There are fewer columns in the
>   INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The
>   number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns
>   specified in the INSERT statement.

```
CREATE TABLE Voorwerp (
voorwerpnummer                  BIGINT                   IDENTITY(30068720558,1)                  
NOT NULL,
titel                           VARCHAR(100)                                                      
NOT NULL,
beschrijving                        VARCHAR(max)                                                      
NOT NULL,
Startprijs                      NUMERIC(10,2)                                                     
NOT NULL,
Betalingswijze                  VARCHAR(20)                                                       
NOT NULL,
betalinginstructie              VARCHAR(80)                                                       
NULL,
plaatsnaam                      VARCHAR(28)                                                       
NOT NULL,
Land                                VARCHAR(35)                                                       
NOT NULL,
Looptijd                            TINYINT                  DEFAULT ((7))                            
NOT NULL,
LooptijdbeginDag                    DATE                                                              
NOT NULL,
LooptijdbeginTijdstip           TIME                                                              
NOT NULL,
Verzendkosten                   NUMERIC (8,2)                                                     
NULL,               
verzendinstructies              VARCHAR (125)                                                     
NULL,
Verkoper                            VARCHAR (255)                                                     
NOT NULL,
Koper                           VARCHAR (255)                                                     
NULL,
LooptijdeindeDag                    AS DATEADD(DAY,Looptijd,looptijdbeginDag),                                                           
looptijdeindeTijdstip           TIME                                                              
NOT NULL,
VeilingGesloten                  BIT                                                              
NOT NULL,
Verkoopprijs                        NUMERIC(10,2)                                                     
NULL,

INSERT INTO Voorwerp(
[titel],
[beschrijving],
[Startprijs],
[Betalingswijze],
[betalinginstructie],
[plaatsnaam],
[Land],
[Looptijd],
[LooptijdbeginDag],
[LooptijdbeginTijdstip],
[Verzendkosten],
[verzendinstructies],
[Verkoper],
[Koper],
[LooptijdeindeDag],
[looptijdeindeTijdstip],
[VeilingGesloten])
VALUES('Stabiele drum/pi..',
'Stabiele drum/pi..',
 50.00,
 'Bank',
'Overschrijving moet...',
'New Vennep',
'Nederland',
7,
'2005-05-19',
'09:10:00',
3.50,
   'Paket post binnen Nederland',
   'Bianca77',
   1,
   '2005-05-26',
   '09:30:00',
   1,
   500
);
```

Comment: In your insert statement, the value , 500 should be removed, or you have to add the columne [Verkoopprijs] into the the INSERT INTO statement after VeilingGesloten.

Comment: I added [Verkoopprijs]  but now a am getting this error  Msg 271, Level 16, State 1, Line 641
The column "LooptijdeindeDag" cannot be modified because it is either a computed column or is the result of a UNION operator.

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice it, yes, please remove the column LooptijdeindeDag from the INSERT INTO statement.

Answer (score 0):

Column `LooptijdeindeDag` is listed in the column list in the INSERT statement.

You need to remove it and it's corresponding value from the insert statement.

Your insert statement should looks like:

```
INSERT INTO Voorwerp(
[titel],
[beschrijving],
[Startprijs],
[Betalingswijze],
[betalinginstructie],
[plaatsnaam],
[Land],
[Looptijd],
[LooptijdbeginDag],
[LooptijdbeginTijdstip],
[Verzendkosten],
[verzendinstructies],
[Verkoper],
[Koper],
[looptijdeindeTijdstip],
[VeilingGesloten])
```

Comment: You are missing a bunch of columns, basically the column [LooptijdeindeDag] should be removed and the column [Verkoopprijs] need to be added the end of the insert into statement